# "Must declare the table variable"

Tags: sql, vb.net, t-sql

I am trying to get this code working in Visual Basic:

In a `SqlDataSource` I have try this SQL command:

```
SELECT * FROM @Parameter1
```

I have created `Parameter1` in my ReportViewer but I get error :

> Must declare the table variable

Any help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot use a parameter to specify the name of a Table or the name of fields.
Parameters could only be used to express the values in a WHERE clause for a SELECT/DELETE/UPDATE or for the values passed to an INSERT/UPDATE statement

Comment: Thank you, I assumed that. Can I somehow dinamicly change table name from which I must get data.

Comment: Probably you need to apply for some event in code-behind but I don't know enough of ReportViewer to help more on this